# Handle private external DTD with dependencies in SAX parser

Tags: java, xml, tomcat, dtd, saxparser

I'm trying to parse XML file with private external DTD specified in DOCTYPE like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE MY1 SYSTEM "my1.dtd">
```

To hanlde this DTD locally for validation I specifed `EntityResolver` for `XMLReader parser`:

```
        //use local DTD
        parser.setEntityResolver(new EntityResolver() {
            @Override
            public InputSource resolveEntity(String publicId, String systemId) throws SAXException, IOException {
                if (systemId.contains(my1Dtd)) {
                    return new InputSource(MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream(MY1_DTD_RESOURCE_PATH));
                } else {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        });
```

This `InputSource` returned correctly, but there is a problem related to DTD: Inside DTD there are references to another DTDs. So I put all DTDs in the same package. But when my application deployed on Tomcat `FileNotFoundException D:\apache-tomcat-6.0.29\bin\my2.dtd (The system cannot find the file specified)` was thrown.

My question is: how can we specify this dependency correctly? Should it be constructed in `resolveEntity` method or I made a mistake in path (`my2.dtd` declared as `<!ENTITY % MY2 SYSTEM "my2.dtd">` inside `my1.dtd` and stored in the same package).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `resolveEntity` should be invoked as well when the parser needs to load the my2.dtd file.

Thus ou need to modify it in this similar way:

```
 public InputSource resolveEntity(String publicId, String systemId) throws SAXException, IOException {
            if (systemId.contains(my1Dtd)) {
                return new InputSource(MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream(MY1_DTD_RESOURCE_PATH));
            } else if (systemId.contains(my2Dtd)) {
                return new InputSource(MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream(MY2_DTD_RESOURCE_PATH));
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

However, to avoid such work you should consider using a resolver, like  [the Apache resolver](http://xerces.apache.org/xml-commons/components/resolver/). This resolver relies on the [OASIS entity resolution / XML catalogs](https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/tc_home.php?wg_abbrev=entity), which allows you to create a catalog in XML format, read by the resolver so that you won't need to modify your code each time you have a new DTD or move it to another place or whatever.
(This resolver package comes bundled with the Apache Xerces distribution, if it already is the parser you are using).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Looks like I misunderstood logic of `resolveEntity` for that moment.